# Bones don't follow animation

Tags: armature, bones

I have another problem,
I started a new model for animation, but I don't know why bones don't follow anymore the cloth modifier?
Previous model works fine, in this model I cannot find a solution, can someone help me where I forgot to apply something?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WXmAsbhc6fk&feature=youtu.be

How to make it work and follow the armature

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q0KMj4zwO8c&feature=youtu.be

again I followed this tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r1w4VoVPixg&t=14s

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115611/discussion-on-question-by-andrej-bones-dont-follow-animation).

Comment: was trying to make simple flag model like i did in previus model and bone still rotating like in this model